# ASP.Net MVC4 with Razor - Best and correct way to acces controler methods in views

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working with ASP.NET but I am fairly new to the ASP.Net MVC 4 with Razor concept. So my question might be basic but I appreciate every help as I couldn't really find a definite answer for days now (Or I am looking for the wrong things). The question is: How do I access a Controller method within my view without using my Index Method?

The scenario:

- I have a database that store some values like date, price etc ... (Variables are defined in the Model.
- I have a controller thats sets a view index
- I have a view that shows Indexpage with the values of my data base.

I want to sum all values of the price colum but dont want to store the result in my db.
In my understanding I access the db via a Method in my Controller class and call this method in my view.

To learn step by step I just defined a fixed value in my controller to see how to show this value in my view.

The code:

```
Model:

[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; } // Amount of an entry

Controller:

     public ActionResult Index()
        {
             return View(db.Amounts.ToList());
        }

      public ActionResult ShowSumOfAllPrices()
        {

            //For testing db is not called yet. Query must be defined and result written to a variable within this mehod
            ViewBag.Price = 2;

            return View();
        }

View:

@*testmethod for displaying sumprize (first just wit test result) via controler*@


    <table>
    <tr>   
        <td>hallo @ViewBag.Price</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The result is not shown as long as I don't define the method content of  `ShowSumOfAllPrices()` (in my controller class) in the `index()` method.

The question is: Is a result of a method in a view only visible if I define it within my `Index()` method in my controller or can I write an extra method like I did and call it in my view? It is working if I c&p the logic of `ShowSumOfAllPrices()` to `Index()`. But I don't think I need to define everything in my index method. If so, it would be a large and fat method. So as far as I see there are 3 possible ways but not all might be "nice" or even working:

1. Define everything in the `Index()` method.
2. Define other methods but call them in the Index method because it is the only way to display it within my view and not using the model because i dont want to store those data in my db
3. I can define other methods and directly call them in my view without having a new page but only the result of this method shown under the content of the currend Index Page.

I hope my question is understandable and this question was not asked like mine before.

Comment: One suggestion: Everything you know about Web Forms you need to forget about it. MVC is a different way of thinking. Have a look at some samples and tutorials over at www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0):

> Define everything in the Index() method.

Controllers are not meant to hold the logic.

> Define other methods but call them in the Index method because it is the only way to display it within my view and not using the model because i dont want to store those data in my db

Don't define other methods in the controller itself. Make other classes and then call those methods in the `Index()` or any suitable controller method. And if you want to display data in the view , then model is the best choice, but you can even store your data in the `ViewBag`

> I can define other methods and directly call them in my view without having a new page but only the result of this method shown under the content of the current Index Page.

If you want to fetch the result of the methods in the same view then this can be the case[might be using same kind of AJAX] but if you want to render other page , then this might be a bad idea.

The **best** thing you can do is to declare a class for your required function as Single responsibility principle and then use the class to do that operation in the method you want to have results in.You can access the controller methods using AJAX and JQuery, just google it out a bit and you will be your own.

Hope this helps.